# Creating Folder Structuring in jsp

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jsp, directory-structure

How can we show a folder structure in jsp ,suppose i have a folder `C:/Company/.....`

I have to just pass `C:/company`  and the jsp will show the folder structure of this path in my page.

Is there any JQuery Plugin to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [jStree](http://www.jstree.com/) as a treeview structure, I use this tree on several domains and it really nice, a free plugin which has a lot of options. The backend you need to do yourself.

Supports:

Various data sources - HTML, JSON, XML

Supports AJAX loading

Drag & drop support

Highly configurable

Theme support + included themes

And more...